# mongoengine filter query not working

Tags: flask-mongoengine

I've defined a `Flavor` Document much like the rest of my models, and **recently** added the `is_archived` field:

```
class Flavor(BaseDocument):
    is_archived = BooleanField(default=False)
```

In a python shell I can verify that my Documents do indeed have the field and are set to a Boolean:

```
for f in Flavor.objects.all():
    print f.is_archived, type(f.is_archived)

>> False <type 'bool>
>> False <type 'bool>
>> ...
```

But when I `filter` the query it returns only the documents I have created since adding the field.

```
Flavor.objects(is_archived=False)
Flavor.objects.filter(is_archived=False)

>> [<Flavor: newFlavor>]
>> [<Flavor: newFlavor>]
```

**How can I update my old Documents to be collected by the filtered query?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out. Perfect example of how carefully framing the question leads naturally to the answer:

```
for f in Flavor.objects.all():
    f.update(set__is_archived=f.is_archived)
```